# Write files to App_Data under medium trust hack?

Tags: asp.net, trust

Is there any way to Write files to App_Data under medium trust hack?

Im sure I've heard about some hack, is that true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to the server itself, so I can't check that. I can only chmod files and folder from my FTP client.

I think my hosting provider needs to grant write permission to the network service account on the App_Data folder.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are able to create new files, but you should be able to write to existing files in the App_Data folder.  But I have honestly never experienced any problems with Medium Trust and writing to the App_Data folder.  Are you sure it has the necessary permissions needed for writing files to the hard drive?